# Single supply amplifier biasing

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, bias, biasing

I'm trying to understand this circuit.

I can see that BW1 is a low pass filter and BW3 removes any DC from the output signal, but what does BW2 do?

If it is acting as a filter, is it a high pass filter or a low pass filter?

[image]

Comment: Both R1-C1 (BW2) and Rload-Cout (BWR3) are HPFs which pass the AC signal.

Comment: The first equation is only true if Ra == Rb. Otherwise it is Ra*Rb/(Ra+Rb) rather than Ra/2.

Answer (score 0):

(1) It is the task of the capacitor C1 to decouple the input signal source from the feedback path for DC as well as very low-frequencies. As mentioned, it forms the highpass BW2. Hence, it allows a fixed DC gain of unity and realizes a quiescent operating point at Vs/2 at the output.

(2) Therefore, for decoupling the amplified output signal from this DC-offset a coupling capacitor Cout is required (highpass BW3 )

(3) Without the capacitor C2 the common-mode noise appearing at the power-supply terminals would be amplified (because it appears also at the non-inv. opamp input). Therefore, it is the purpose of C2 to ground the midpoint between RA and RB (the non-inv. input) for frequencies above BW1. (Remember: For split supply this terminal is also connected to ground.)

Comment: Thank you, that all makes sense now.